# Method lastRenderedFrame NOT working right

Tags: ios, skmaps

There is a point in my app that I have to grab the last rendered image of the map view to use later on as a thumbnail, but when I call:

```
UIImage *img = [_mapView lastRenderedFrame];
```

the returned image isn't actually what the map view was displaying, is an opaque version of it and less detailed.

Note: I'm using the SDK 2.3.0 on an iPhone 5S with iOS 8.1

**Edit:**

I've tested that this problem is only shown when the map scale value is lower than 10, if is higher than 10 the method works fine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in the demo project?

Comment: @Ando Yes I can reproduce this issue in the demo project. See my edit, the problem seems to be related with the map scale.

Comment: There is indeed an issue when the zoom level is less than 10-> Bug. There are no workarounds for this but the fix will be available in the next release (2.4).

Comment: @Ando Thanks, I'll be waiting for the next release.